# What is the @ notation in file upload? (specifically facebook ads api)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, facebook-ads-api

I am using the Facebook Ads API and am wondering about Ad Image creation. This page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adimage/#create, makes it look pretty simple, except I'm not sure what's going on with the 'test.jpg=@test.jpg'. What is the @ for and how does it work?

I currently make the post request as described in the API docs (the above link) with a parameter 'pic.jpg' with value '@https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/my/image.jpg' but the response is an empty array instead of the JSON object with the 'images' key as shown in the API docs (the above link).

Can someone explain the idea/process/syntax of specifying files in HTTP requests, or perhaps more specific to Facebook Ads API? I'm not sure what is at play here.

EDIT:
(I should mention that I'm using python requests library.)

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to upload an Image on Facebook Ads API you can't give a URL you will have to provide the real path for it.

in many cases you can use 'image_url' directly & give the URL of the image, but in some cases you will need to upload the image to facebook and use the HASH provided by it.

PHP/cURL implementation

```
    $myPhoto = realpath('c.jpg');

       $ch = curl_init();

       $data = array('name' => "@{$myPhoto}",'access_token' => "{$access_token}");

       $urlStr = "https://graph.facebook.com/act_{$ad_account_id}/adimages";

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlStr);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    

       $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

to know how to POST a file with Python (refer: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Also you can use this library it does all the work for you : https://github.com/jgorset/facepy

Answer (score 0):

The @ feature is to upload a file. It is supported by curl and PHP for example. So if you add a https link it is not strange that it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, so it's not strange that it doesn't work, but why and how do I fix it?

Comment: The API require that you upload an image. So you can't give it a URL. Download the image locally and then upload it to Facebook

Comment: Is this true for the Ads API but not for the the general API?

Comment: It it totally up to the API if it allow a URL or not. Reading the documentation you linked to I can't find anything that say that it would allow a URL. If other APIs allow a URL I assume they say so